# What does "the alternative side of things" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyAKUEmzMPk&feature=youtu.be&t=120) video, I heard the following sentence:

> He and I have always been **on the alternative side of things**, our views of what's going on in this world is a skewed one.

I looked up this phrase but didn't find any related entries. I'm also not sure if saying 'a skewed one' is correct here since the speaker was obviously describing their views which is a plural noun.

Comment: He means: opposite side of things. Sometimes,when people talk they don't always have the best wording.

Comment: She's talking about being part of a counter-culture.  So, alternative means other than mainstream, and skewed means deviating from the norm.  Also, she's speaking extemporaneously, in a distracting environment, and she frequently seems to change course in the middle of her sentences.  The change in grammatical number here is not a very surprising mistake.